# compare header text with an array in protractor

Tags: arrays, protractor

I have around 11 columns in md-table. i can compare 10 header labels but one is having a line break in its label. I dont know how to compare that one.

```
<th md-column="" class="md-column ng-isolate-scope"><span>Accessorial<br>(Agent Fee / Customer Charge)</span></th>
```

this is the html for the line break header label. can someone please help me in comparing this column label.

My code is below.

```
colheadernames = ['a','b','c'];
       cnt = element.all(by.css('.md-column')).then(function(arr){
        for ( i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i].getText().then(function(text) {
                items.push(text.trim());
            });
        }


  }).then(function(){
        expect(items).toEqual(colheadernames);
    });
```

Thanks,
mallesh

Comment: Try with this 
text= text.replace(/\n/g, " ");//it will replace new line with " "
items.push(text.trim());

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through each column you can use array.map() to solve your problem, Look at below example

```
var colheadernames = ['a','b','c'];
var colheaderFrombrowser =element.all(by.css('.md-column')).getText().then(function(arr){
    return arr.map(function(arrayValue){
           return arrayValue.replace(/\n/g, " ");  //will replace all line breaks with " "
      })
})

expect(colheadernames).toEqual(colheaderFrombrowser)
```

Comment: Hi Sudharsan,thanks for your answer. but i get this error.

    Expected [ 'Segment Ref #', 'Agent', 'Customer', 'Consignee', 'Accessorial (
Agent Fee / Customer Charge)' ] to equal ManagedPromise::309 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"}.

Comment: hey i used my same code and used your replace. it is working for me now. do you know which function to use to concatenate strings. i am using concat but i get an error saying - concat is not defined.